# Would like to setup my own mining pool for PPC Peercoin

Tags: mining-pools, asic, antminer, peercoin

I have 8 different antminer ASIC's and I would like to setup my own mining pool.  I would like to mine PPC aka Peercoin.  Everything seems to be very old as far as tutorials and I am looking for something that is possible for a non-programmer to get running.